# How to host java app for a domain homepage

Tags: java, server, hosting

I have my application developed in Java and located in my host as http://myhost.com:8080/myapp. I am using bluehost for my hosing service.

I want to access this app when I am hitting http://myhost.com..

I went to lot of articles in this but confused a lot. Also there is no clear documentations for this.

How to do this? can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using htaccess file.

Found htaccess file in my hosting server and create redirection for my domain, now everything looks good.

Hope it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

use apache server as a proxy server which will use your server name ( http://myhost.com) and redirect that request to your running app url ( http://myhost.com:8080/myapp). ie port forwarding concept.

like,

use following in your apache configuration file.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyRequests Off
      ServerName www.myhost.com
      ServerAlias myhost.com
      ProxyPass / http://myhost.com:8080/myapp/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost.com:8080/myapp/
    </VirtualHost>
```

To acheive this you need to configure so many things.so read any appropriate documentation.

Comment: I am having .htaccess file only.